# Angular JS unable to catch div elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<body>
<button ng-click="AppendSample()">
  Show
</button>
<div id="divID">
 OK TEXT
</div>
<script>
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.AppendSample = function() {
     var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
     alert(myElement);     
    }
}
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to `alert` the div element with id `divID` but the alert box come out with `[[object HTMLDivElement]]` instead of `OK TEXT`. Where is my problem? How I get appropriate alert? Thank you.

Comment: `angular.element` returns the element, which is an object - I assume you're after `myElement.text()`

Comment: Try `alert(myElement).text ();` and check the jQuery documentation for more information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular's jQlite functions. According to the [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

> jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular
>   to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. jqLite
>   implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal
>   of having a very small footprint.

Make sure your jQuery is loaded before the angular.js after then you could simply use

```
$("#divID").html();
```

OR

```
var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
alert(myElement.html());
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of alerting the element itself you need to alert element.HTML()

Ie

```
var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) ); 
alert(myElement.html());
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there short form of  `angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) )`

Answer (score 0):

The other responses use jQuery/jQlite to return the HTML contained in the `<div></div>`. If you just want the text—which would make sense if your ultimate goal really is an alert—you can retrieve that with plain JavaScript using:

```
document.getElementById("divID").textContent
```